# Wordpress 3.1 makes my drop down menu dissapear, jquery dont work

Tags: jquery, customization

Please help,

After i upgrade to WP 3.1 just now, all my site menus not working, no drop down menu, and the jquery countdown not working. please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're not accidentally loading jQuery 1.5.0 from somewhere like Google's CDN or something. jQuery 1.5.0 is *not* backwards compatible, and the timing of its release prevented it from making it into WordPress 3.1.